# How to verify if Kafka work fine by spring admin

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

I tried to use spring admin to check Kafka connection status.The background is I want create a common jar to check modules Kafka connection.when modules depend on Kafka,in my opinion, I could get a bean from spring containers and check if Kafka work fine by bean.But it seems failed, so any suggestions? What you guys solutions to do Kafka health check? Following is my codes.

```
@ConditionalOnBean(KafkaTemplate.class)
@Component
public class KafkaHealthIndicator extends AbstractHealthIndicator {

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate kafkaTemplate;


    @Override
    protected void doHealthCheck(Health.Builder builder) throws Exception {
        try {
            kafkaTemplate.metrics();
            builder.up();
        }catch (Exception ex){
            builder.down();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your `KafkaHealthIndicator` has a proper logic.

However it looks like just indicator is not enough, there must be something like `HealthContributor` yet.

I don't know why we don't have for Spring for Apache Kafka out-of-the-box, but you probably can follow whatever we have there so far for RabbitMQ. See classes `RabbitHealthIndicator` and `RabbitHealthContributorAutoConfiguration` for examples to follow.

Comment: KafkaHealthIndicator is not available in ```  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
  </dependency>
``` . i use `3.1.0` version.

Comment: The `HealthIndicator` abstraction is a part of Spring Boot. However there is still no one for Kafka. Therefore your comment is misleading.